# Local variable may not be initialized

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a grade calculator. Everything is working to specifications except the program is not handling the conditionals correctly to output the right letter grade.

Any help on this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeCalculator {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        String name;
        String major;
        int attendance;
        int homework;
        int project1;
        int project2;
        int midterm;
        int finalexam;
        int extra;
        String finalgrade;
        double attweight = 0.05;
        double hwweight = 0.35;
        double project1weight = 0.075;
        double project2weight = 0.075;
        double midtermweight = 0.20;
        double finalweight = 0.25;
        double totalgrade;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your name? ");
        name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your major? ");
        major = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your attendance grade (out of 100)? ");
        attendance = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is your homework grade (out of 100)? ");
        homework = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is your project 1 grade? ");
        project1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is your project 2 grade? ");
        project2 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is your midterm grade? ");
        midterm = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is your final grade? ");
        finalexam = in.nextInt();
        if(attendance > 100 || homework > 100 || project1 > 100 || project2 >100 || midterm > 100 || finalexam > 100) {
            System.out.println("Your grade cannot exceed 100");
        }
        totalgrade = ((attendance * attweight) + (homework * hwweight) + (project1 * project1weight) + (project2 * project2weight) + (midterm * midtermweight) + (finalexam * finalweight));
        if(totalgrade > 93 && totalgrade < 100){
            finalgrade = "A";
        }
        if(totalgrade > 89 && totalgrade < 93){
            finalgrade = "A-";
        }
        if(totalgrade > 86 && totalgrade < 90){
            finalgrade = "B+";
        }
        if(totalgrade > 82 && totalgrade < 87){
            finalgrade = "B";
        }
        if(totalgrade > 79 && totalgrade < 83){
            finalgrade = "B-";
        }
        if(totalgrade > 76 && totalgrade < 80){
            finalgrade = "C+";
        }
        if(totalgrade > 72 && totalgrade < 77){
            finalgrade = "C";
        }
        if(totalgrade > 69 && totalgrade < 73){
            finalgrade = "C-";
        }
        if(totalgrade > 59 && totalgrade < 70){
            finalgrade = "D";
        }
        if(totalgrade < 60){
            finalgrade = "F";
        }

        System.out.println("Your name is " + name + " and your major is " + major + ". Your attendance grade is " + attendance + ", your homework grade is " + homework + ", your project one grade is " + project1 + ", your project two grade is " + project2 + ", your midterm grade is " + midterm + ", your final exam grade is" + finalexam + ". Your total grade is " + totalgrade + " and your letter grade is " + finalgrade);
    }
}
```

Error:

> The local variable finalgrade may not have been initialized

Comment: What value do you think `finalgrade` has if `totalgrade` is 150? What value do you think `finalgrade` has if `totalgrade` is exactly equal to 93?

Comment: you should give a value to `String finalgrade = "";`

Comment: Better yet, change all the totalgrade `if` statements (except first) to `else if`, replace final `if` with `else` and remove `totalgrade < 100`. Now it will be *definitely assigned*, and compile error will go away, *without* initializing it to a dummy blank string.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Elaboration

You already told us the problem. You need to initialize finalgrade. You did initialize it inside your conditional statements, however this is not guaranteed to happen when try to read the variable's value in your output (because the initialization only happens if you satisfy a condition) so the compiler gets mad. An easy work around would be to start out setting finalgrade to the empty string.

```
String finalgrade = "";
```

Also, look at your conditional statements. You're excluding 93, maybe other numbers. It would be better to use 'else if', after the first 'if' statement.